# Need help getting started with a partial fraction $\int\frac{\sqrt{x+25}}{x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

I'm having trouble determining how to get started with this problem.  I tried rationalizing the fraction, but I didn't think that was correct after I got started.  Here is the problem:

$$\int\frac{\sqrt{x+25}}{x}$$

Edit, not looking for someone to solve this for me, just initial support with getting it going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A small start:** Let $u^2=x+25$. We end up integrating a rational function. After a while, partial fractions will be involved.

Comment: How did you know to make that substitution?

Comment: @inquisitor Because the square root is the worst part of the integrand.  Any $u$-substitution that simplifies the problem is a good place to start.

Comment: An old joke, one calls it a $U$-substitution because we substitute for the Ugly part. Don't like square roots, let's get rid of it.

Comment: I'm sure it's obvious that I'm still new to integral calculus, but I thought that $U$ substitution is done when its derivative exist in the integral.  Or perhaps I overlooked it?

Comment: but the derivative of x+25 exists! it is $1$

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien so does that mean that $du=dx$?  I'm sorry if the answer is painfully obvious, I'm just trying to understand and having trouble visualizing what would be in the numerator?

Comment: @inquisitor well, you have to be careful, I missed at first that Andre set $u^2=x+25$, so $du$ isn't $dx$

Comment: We have $dx=2u\,du$, so we are integrating $\frac{2u^2}{u^2-25}$. Divide. We get $2+\frac{50}{u^2-25}$. Now partial fractions.

Answer (score 1):

Do a $u$ substitution of $u = \sqrt{x + 25}$ and then try long division on the result.

Answer (score 1):

By The substitution $t^2 = x + 25 \implies 2tdt = dx $, then we obtain:

$$ \int \frac{\sqrt{x + 25}}{x} = - 2 \int \frac{t^2}{t^2 - 25} = -2 \int \frac{t^2 - 25 + 25}{t^2 - 25}   $$

$$ = -2 \int dt -2\int\frac{25}{t^2 -  5^2} = -2t -50 \int \frac{1}{t^2 - 5^2} = -2t -50 \frac{1}{-25} Arctan(t) + C $$

$$ = -2t + 2 Arctan (t) + C = -2 \sqrt{x + 25} + 2 Arctan( \sqrt{x + 25 } ) + C$$

$C \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Where you see arctan, I see partial fraction

Comment: great ! :) :) :)

Comment: I said that so you'd change it, you dont get arctan

Comment: Your answer is wrong.  Please check.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{\sqrt{x+25}}{x} d x &=\int \frac{x+25}{x \sqrt{x+25}} d x \\
&=2 \int \frac{x+25}{x} d(\sqrt{x+25}) \\
&=2 \int 1 d(\sqrt{x+25})+50 \int \frac{d(\sqrt{x+25})}{(\sqrt{x+25})^{2}-5^2}\\
&=2 \sqrt{x+25}+10 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x+25}-5}{\sqrt{x+25}+5}\right|+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Are you going to post the same kind of answer to all the questions about similar integrals on this site? Why don't you try answering some difficult problems instead?

Comment: @Lai, $x=25\tan^2 t$ would work just as fine